# I get an error when trying to add OrchardCms

Tags: orchardcms

I get this error on both Visual Studio 2015 and 2019

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddOrchardCms();
}
```

'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOrchardCms' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [SOLVED] Make sure if you are using VS2019 you select .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Please post this as an answer and mark the answer as accepted. This will prevent the question from popping up in the "Unanswered" category.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] Make sure if you are using VS2019 you select .NET Core 3.1